# How to map multiple Controller in java Spring MVC in context.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 controllers(Home,Rest) in my application and I would like to add mapping for both of them in web.xml and applicationContext.xml.How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Please read and include this guide in your project it is helpfull for your.

> 1. Please define your class is controller using **@Controller** annotation
> 2. include this in **web.xml** file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</servlet>
```

> 3.Write this in **servlet-context.xml** file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mypack.controller" />
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

In base-package you can give your root package name.

When your web request is arrived in servlet-context.xml file, it is redirected to specific controller using base-package attribute you have defined.